# Unable to uninstall a dll in system32 folder

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, wix3.7

My MSI built in WiX 3.7, installs a DLL in `system32` folder. While uninstalling, all components are getting removed except the dll in system32 folder. I could see this DLL in SharedDLLs Registry entry `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs]` and reference count set to `1`.

This DLL is very specific to  my application and no other application uses it. If I delete the DLL's registry entry (SharedDlls) and try to uninstall, the DLL is getting removed from `system32` folder.

My primary requirement is when I try to uninstall, the DLL in `system32` folder must also be removed. Can someone suggest how to achieve it?

If any flags in WiX code could prevent the entry of this DLL in sharedDlls `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs]`.

Comment: What is the file doing in system32 if it is specific to your application? Is it a driver file?

Answer (score 0):

In wix, the component that installs your dll should have the attribute SharedDllRefCount="No", or just don't explicitly set the SharedDllRefCount attribute at all (default value is "No).  After you build your MSI, double-check that the attribute column in the Component table for your dll's component doesn't have the 0x0008 bit set (msidbComponentAttributesSharedDllRefCount - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007(v=vs.85).aspx).